How do software patents work with open source being international and patents being national?
Patents apply nationally, as per this answer:

There is no international patent. Each country protects IP under its own national laws and registration system.
A typical route would be to file an application under the Patent Cooperation Treaty (PCT), and then pursue national patent applications in each country that you plan to exploit your invention.

Software, particularly open source software, is distributed internationally such that is is not always obvious under what jurisdiction the transfer happened.
For example, it is in the news that Nintendo claiming patent protection on gameplay elements of a competitors game, Palworld, based on three Japanese patents.   I assume they have not filed these patents in all 193 UN member states.
Suppose Alice lived in a country where Nintendo had not filed a patent for these gameplay elements, perhaps even not in the PCT, and she wrote OpenPalworld that infringed these patents and released it under the GPL v3.  Suppose Bob lived in a country where Nintendo had filed these patents and downloaded and played the game.  Suppose Charlie, while living in in such a country or not, downloaded and redistributed the game, unaltered or altered.
What activities in what jurisdictions do patents restrict?  Who in the above scenario could Nintendo sue for what?

Copyright and contract law (i.e. software licenses) is national as well.

You are conflating two different intellectual property concepts:

Open source is about the copyright status of a work;
Patents are about the state-granted monopoly to make, use, or sell a particular invention.

It is certainly possible to get open-source access to technology that would infringe a patent when used.
Patents only apply nationally. This clear from any country's patent statute. E.g. 35 U.S.C. § 271 says: "whoever without authority makes, uses, offers to sell,
or sells any patented invention, within the United States or imports into the United States any
patented invention during the term of the patent therefor, infringes the patent."
You assert that:

Alice lived in a country where Nintendo does not have a patent; and
Alice wrote something that "infringed" Nintendos patents.

First: things don't infringe patents. The making, use, or sale of a thing can infringe a patent. And Alice can't infringe a patent if she's only doing things in a country where the patent doesn't exist. So, I don't know what you mean by that second sentence.
In any case, a country's prohibitions on doing patent-infringing things (that is: the making, use, or sale of the invention, the scope of which is described in the patent's "claims") only applies within the country.

So Bob infringed the patent when he used the software he downloaded, because he's in a country where the patent is in force. Right? And Alice might be guilty of contributory infringement by making it available to people in that country?
